# jQuery slide up malfunction

Tags: jquery

When i mouse over the element, it slides up fast then back down but disappears before you know it.

```
jQuery('.touchcarousel-item').on('mouseover', function(){

    jQuery('.tc-desc').css('height', '+=292').stop(true).slideUp();

});

jQuery('.touchcarousel-item').on('mouseout', function(){

    jQuery('.tc-desc').css('height', '58px');

});
```

Comment: Show your HTML. Use the stack Snippet of create a fiddle.

Comment: @Sleek Geek Better than that, here's a link to the site: http://codecreatif.com/c6/ - Hover the slider where the thumbnail titles are.

Comment: @user2984926 it looks like you're adding 292 pixels for every instance that your mouse is over the image. I would suggest using `hover` or `mouseenter`

Comment: @ntgCleaner changed to mouseenter but still the same issu

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do? It seems that you're adding 292px immediately, then stopping any animation, then sliding it up so it hides.  But then, you don't display it again when your mouse leaves.

Comment: @ntgCleaner I'm simply wanting the box to slide up to reveal the hidden content, then slide back to it's original state on mouseout

Comment: @user2984926, Ok, so why are you adding the height incrementally rather than specifying an absolute height?  `slideUp()` takes care of the animation, but it also makes the element `display:none;` at the end of the animation.  You might also need to add `slideDown()` on your mouseout function, or at the very least, add `'display', 'block'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68367/discussion-between-user2984926-and-ntgcleaner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to animate the height of the element.  Using slide up or slide down will shrink and hide or display the element you already have:

```
$('.touchcarousel-item').hover(function(){ 
    $('.tc-desc').animate({'height':'100%'}); 
}, function(){ 
    $('.tc-desc').animate({'height':'65px'}); 
}
```